# CellTree remove blue selection bar

Tags: gwt

I've customized CellTree so that checkboxes are used to select items.
But I don't how I can remove default blue bar when I select the item ?

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the CellTree CSS so that the selected item classes (cellTreeKeyboardSelectedItem and cellTreeSelectedItem ) do not modify the color anymore.

See [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/QVD5lGOYeu0) for how to introduce your own custom CSS to your CellTree:

> CellTree has a constructor that takes a CellTree.Ressource instance.
>
> [...]
>
> You can create an interface that extends CellTree.Ressources (which is a ClientBundle) for overwriting images. To overwrite CSS create an interface that extends CellTree.Style (which extends CssRessource) and return this custom style in your custom CellTree.Ressource interface using "YourStyle cellTreeStyle();"
>
> `public interface TreeResources extends CellTree.Resources {
>           @Source("../CellTree.css")
>           public CellTree.Style cellTreeStyle();
>   }`

---

Alternately, you can set your own SelectionModel in the CellTree so that none of the checkbox-selected items in the tree are actually selected (= get the selection CSS class) in the tree model. You will then have to handle the checkbox selection on your own, though.